# Is it possible to let system notify my app when user change system/accessibility settings font size?

Tags: android

I want to know whenever the user changes the font size from settings. Instead of checking the font size upon login, I think the best and most accurate way is to simply get notified whenever user changes the font size. I know in iOS it's doable. Wondering is it possible in android?

Comment: Why is it important for your app to know when the font size has changed?

Comment: We want to adjust our UI according to the font size the user prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in way to do this however you could create and register a [ContentObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) for System Settings and in your `onChange` event you will get notified of any changes.

> **ContentObserver**: Receives call backs for changes to content. Must be implemented by objects which are added to a ContentObservable.

The only problem is you will get notified for *any* system setting change, not just font size.

Comment: Yeah.. I don't want to get notified all the time... all I want is font size. I thought to checking it all the time is not quite efficient. That's why I'm wondering can we only get notified when it actually changes instead of checking all the time. But if there's no way to do it, it's fine. I know where to check it in my app.